# symfony2 のwelcomeページが表示されない

Tags: php, symfony2

下記のsymfony2 のチュートリアルをもとに環境構築しているのですが
welcomepageが表示されず困っております。

http://docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#quick-tour-big-picture-built-in-server

【エラー内容】

> No route found for "GET /" 　404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException 　1
>   linked Exception: 　ResourceNotFoundException »
>
> ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /"" at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 2059

コンポーネント等、必要なファイルはインストールしたのですが
何か他に見落としている部分がないか、どなたかご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 2.7 LTS を前提とします。`http://localhost:8000/app/example` にアクセスして、Homepage の文字列が表示されますか？

日本語のドキュメントには反映されていませんが、Symfony 2.7 LTS で **Symfony Installer** によるプロジェクトのセットアップが推奨されるようになりました。

**Symfony Installer** のセットアップ方法は[ダウンロード](http://symfony.com/download)のページで「install the Symfony Installer」の青いテキストをクリックすれば、表示されます。

Linux と Mac OS X は次のコマンドを実行します。私が自分の Mac OS X に導入したとき、sudo は使いませんでした。

```
$ sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Windows の場合、次の通りです。

```
c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

/app/example を表示するために使われるコントローラーは `src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php`、テンプレートは `app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig` です。

コントローラーの練習の例として、`/app/foo` にアクセスすると「fooさん、こんにちは」と表示されるコードを示します。HTML エスケープを考慮する必要のない練習では、戻り値に Response オブジェクトを使うと便利です。

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/app/{name}", name="homepage_hello")
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return new Response($name.'さん、こんにちは');
    }
}
```

JSON を返したい場合、JsonResponse オブジェクトを返します。

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

public function someAction()
{
    return new JsonResponse(["key" => "value"]);
}
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！

app/exampleは問題なく表示されました。
調べたところ、参照したHPがスタンダードエディションを利用していたため、ファイルの構成が違っていただけのようです・・・

tutorialとして扱いたかったのですが、どうやらこちらがダウンロードできない限りは公式しか頼れないようですね・・・

Comment: 問題が解消されたのでご報告です。

上記に関しては、バージョンをそろえてあげればファイル構成も同じなので問題なく動作しました。
コンポーザー等もバージョンをそろえる必要があるので気をつけないとですね・・・