# app_dev.php/ にアクセスすると File not found が返ってきます。

Tags: nginx, symfony2

現在、以下の内容で symfony2 に取り組んでいますが、最初から躓いていますのでお力を貸して下さい。

#### 環境

CentOS 6.6 (※Windows7 上の VirtualBox で実行)
nginx/1.8.0
symfony/2.7.2

#### インストール手順

```
$ sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ su root
# cd /home
# symfony new www 2.7
# chown nginx -R /home/www
# chgrp nginx -R /home/www
# chmode a+rwx /home/www/app/cache
# chmode a+rwx /home/www/app/logs
```

#### 確認したこと

`http://hogehoge/config.php` にアクセス
→ Welcome! Your configuration looks good to run Symfony.が表示される。
　正常に動作していると思います。

#### 困っていること

以下のサイトを参考に進めているつもりですが、後述するURLでアクセスするとそれぞれエラーになってしまうため、正常に動作していないと思われます。

http://docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#quick-tour-big-picture-built-in-server

- `http://hogehoge/app_dev.php` にアクセス
  → No route found for "GET /" が表示される。
- `http://hogehoge/app_dev.php/` にアクセス
  → File not found が表示される。
- `http://hogehoge/app/example/` にアクセス
  → File not found が表示される。

お手数をお掛けして申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: hogehoge/app/example はいかがでしょうか？http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/12208/568 の回答のように Symfony 2.7 ではデフォルトページは変わっています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
hogehoge/app/example にアクセスしてみましたが、
hogehoge/app/example/ と同様に File not found. が表示されます。

Comment: hogehoge/app.php/app/example、hogehoge/app_dev.php/app/example はどうでしょうか？Nginx でうまくゆかないなら、 PHP のビルトインサーバー (php app/console server:run) はどうでしょうか？Symfony のための Nginx の設定ファイルの例は次のページで公開されています。http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
教えて頂いた Nginxの設定ファイル（/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf）を
見なおしたところ、リライトの設定を間違えていました。
今、試したところ、、、
app.php/app/example　は　404 Not Found でしたが
app/example は Homepage. が表示され
app_dev.php/app/example　は、Homepage. とページ下部にはボタン？のようなものが表示されました。

ありがとうございました！

この件とは別で恐縮ですが、symfony2.7 を使用した入門サイトをご存じないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメント欄の Symfony2.7 の勉強の進め方について回答します。現時点では古いバージョンを対象としたチュートリアルのコードが使えるかは自分で確かめるしかないです。

最初の段階ではちょっとしたミスでうまくゆかないことが多いので、こまめに質問してください。困っていることをことばで表現することで、何が問題なのかがはっきりすることはよくあります。

私が Symfony 2.7 で検証した内容の一覧は、[こちら](http://blog.sarabande.jp/tagged/symfony2.7)から見ることができます。

最小限必要な知識の例として次の内容を挙げます。

- ルーティングの表記にアノテーションが使える。
- HTTP ヘッダーやボディの読み書きに Request/Response オブジェクトを使う。
- セッションの管理に Session オブジェクトを使う。
- mysql/mysqli/PDO の代わりに Doctrine DBAL を使うことができる。

  ```
  /**
   * @Route("/app/example", name="homepage")
   */

  public function indexAction()
  {
      return new Response('Hello');
  }

  // Request
  $request = $this->getRequest();
  $foo = $request->request->get('foo', 'デフォルト値');
  $token = $request->headers->get('X-CSRF-Token')

  // Response
  $response = new Response('Hello', 200);
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');

  return $response;

  // Session
  $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
  $session->set('bar', 'some value');
  $bar = $session->get('bar');

  // Doctrine DBAL

  // app/config/parameters.yml に接続情報を記載した上で
  // コマンドラインからデータベースを生成する
  // php app/console doctrine:database:create

  $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
  $ret = $dbh->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM test_table");
  ```

勉強時間を十分に確保できない場合や教えてくれる人がいないのであれば、Doctrine ORM やフォーム、ユーザー管理機能などは使わずにアプリの開発を進める選択肢があります。

かぎられた知識と時間のなかで動くコードを書いた上で、冷却期間をおいて、洗練されたコードに書き換えるというのはよくあることです。

Symfony のフォームクラスを使わない場合に注意が必要なことはリクエストの強要攻撃 (CSRF) の対策を自分で実装する必要があることです。

Symfony によるサンプルコードは[こちらの記事](http://blog.sarabande.jp/post/124136118378)をご参照ください。平易な PHP によるコードの例は[こちらの記事](http://blog.sarabande.jp/post/88201025803)をご参照ください。

かんたんに説明すると、フォームの隠しフィールドもしくは HTTP ヘッダーから送信されてきたトークンもしくはナンスをサーバーが検証する必要があるということです。

初心者の段階では PHP のフォームの動作確認はブラウザーを使う機会が多いと思いますが、HTTP  メソッド (POST や GET)、ヘッダーやボディの値によってレスポンスの内容を変えたい場合、curl や httpie などのコマンドツール、Guzzle のような HTTP クライアントのライブラリが検証に便利です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
返事が非常に遅くなって申し訳ございません。

教えて頂いた内容を１つずつ確認したのですが、以下の事が理解できませんでした。

・ルーティングの表記にアノテーションが使える。

この件は、色々なサイトに掲載されていたのですが
どう使えば良いのか、分かりませんでした。
開発工数が下がるということなので、是非、理解したいのですが、、、
教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

「勉強時間を十分に確保できない場合や教えてくれる人がいないのであれば、
Doctrine ORM やフォーム、ユーザー管理機能などは使わずにアプリの開発を進める選択肢があります。」

この件ですが、従来、ZendFramework(2ではありません)とCodeIgniterを使って
手作り？で実装しています。
（contorolerやmodel、viewは手組みという意味です）
なので、出来れば従来通りの開発方法がピンとくるのですが、symfonyだとどうやればいいのか？
と悩んでいます。
どのサイトを見てもコマンド入力で色々と自動的に生成すると書いているように見えて・・・

返事が遅くなって失礼しましたが、よろしければお知恵をお貸し下さい。

Comment: 別の質問を立てていただけますか？タイトルは「ルーティングの書き方」、「Doctrine ORM を使わずに SQL を直接書きたい」、「Doctrine ORM を使わないバリデーション」のような感じでよいと思います。

Comment: masakielasticさま、ありがとうございます。
それでは、「symfony2でアノテーションを使用したルーティングの書き方」と「app/consoleを使わずにプログラムを作成する方法」にしようと思います。